# Multiple render targets and pixel shader outputs terminology

Tags: directx, fragment-shader, multiple-render-targets

I'm a little confused on the jargon: does [Multiple Render Targets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Render_Targets) (MRT) refer to outputting from a pixel shader to multiple elements in a `struct`? That is, when one says "MRT is to write to multiple textures", are multiple elements interleaved in a single output texture, or do you specify multiple discrete output textures?

By the way, from what I understand, at least for DX9, all the elements of this struct need to be of the same size. Does this restriction still apply to DX11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple discrete output textures.  You'd set up several individual render targets, each in exactly the same way as you set up one render target, then specify a list of them rather than a single one when you bind them to be drawn to.

In DX11, the render targets can be different formats and color depths.  I'm not aware of any restrictions on this.  You can e.g. use floating point render targets together with 8-bit integer ones.  However, all the render targets must have the same pixel dimensions, e.g. 1280x720.